# Having not null foreign key reference nullable column

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Say I have the following tables:

```
User (
  ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , providerID INT
)

ProviderPlan(
  planID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , providerID INT NOT NULL
)
```

Then I want to make a foreign key mapping the two tables:

```
ALTER TABLE ProviderPlan ADD FOREIGN KEY (providerID) REFERENCES User(providerID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

My best guess for the error is because one column is nullable while the other is not.  If this is the case, how can I setup a nullable column in a reference table as a not null foreign key in another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error you are getting has nothing to do with one column being nullable and one not. 
You are getting this error because the column `providerID` is not a key of any kind according to your table structure.
So you can't add it as a foreign key to another table.

To remedy this, you either have to make it part of a key or rethink if it actually should be part of one or if you should drop the foreign key constraint all together.